# How to apply the actionButton "Upate View" in Shiny in R?

Tags: r, user-interface, ggplot2, shiny, action-button

This is my original code :

```
library(shiny)
library("neuralnet")
require(ggplot2)

load("C:/gambit/NeuralNetwork.Rdata")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12, class = "well",
           h4("Neural Network Plot"),

           plotOutput("main_plot"),

           hr(),

           numericInput(inputId = "w",
                       label = "Weight(w):",
                       value = 5),

           numericInput(inputId = "b",
                       label = "Biased(b):",
                       value = 5))))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    traininginput <-  as.data.frame(runif(50, min=0, max=100))
    trainingoutput <- sqrt(traininginput)
    trainingdata <- cbind(traininginput,trainingoutput)
    colnames(trainingdata) <- c("Input","Output")
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(input$w, input$b), threshold=0.01)
    print(net.sqrt)
    plot(net.sqrt)
    testdata <- as.data.frame((1:13)^2)  #Generate some squared numbers
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata) #Run them through the neural network
    class(net.results)
    print(net.results)
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                         as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")
    head(cleanoutput)
    lm1<- lm(NeuralNetOutput~ ExpectedOutput, data = cleanoutput)

    ggplot(data = cleanoutput, aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + geom_point() +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1
                  , color="brown", size=0.5)})}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The code that I tried :

```
library(shiny)
library("neuralnet")
require(ggplot2)

load("C:/gambit/NeuralNetwork.Rdata")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12, class = "well",
           h4("Neural Network Plot"),

           plotOutput("main_plot"),

           hr(),

           numericInput(inputId = "w",
                       label = "Weight(w):",
                       value = 5),

           numericInput(inputId = "b",
                       label = "Biased(b):",
                       value = 5), 

           actionButton("update", "Update View"))))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    traininginput <-  as.data.frame(runif(50, min=0, max=100))
    trainingoutput <- sqrt(traininginput)
    trainingdata <- cbind(traininginput,trainingoutput)
    colnames(trainingdata) <- c("Input","Output")
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(input$w, input$b), threshold=0.01)
    print(net.sqrt)
    plot(net.sqrt)
    testdata <- as.data.frame((1:13)^2)  #Generate some squared numbers
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata) #Run them through the neural network
    class(net.results)
    print(net.results)
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                         as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")
    head(cleanoutput)
    lm1<- lm(NeuralNetOutput~ ExpectedOutput, data = cleanoutput)

    ggplot(data = cleanoutput, aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + geom_point() +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1
                  , color="brown", size=0.5)})}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I wish to add an `actionButton` that really works so that I can Update my view instead of let it update automatically. What should I put inside my `server.R` ?

And is there a better to present my script? As I am quite new to `shiny`, I hope I can get some little guide/hints from anyone of you..

Do you guys need the `R.data`? If need it I can email it to you guys.. thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,  can you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This means that you have to use some data that everybody have, such as `mtcars` or `iris`. Concerning your question, you are probably looking for [observeEvent](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html)

Comment: @bretauv hi, can you give me your email? So that I can send you the R.data so that it is more precise haha

Comment: No, you have to provide a functional example. What happens if somebody tries to understand your problem in a year? You won't necessarily want or be able to send your .RData file. There is already an answer for this question, but for the next ones, please include a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data nor do I need to derive a neural network to demonstrate how to control reactivity. But some design considerations for your shiny app:

1. Don't mix data derivation and table/plot output. If you ever need to look at a portion of the data in another reactive block, you're out of luck, since you discard the results at the end of the plot. I suggest you have at least three different reactive chunks here: data being used, trained neural net, and plot output.
2. In all blocks of `render*`, `reactive`, and `observe` (and some others), any kind of reactive data or object can trigger change of the block. Based on my first recommendation, if you have a `dat <- reactive(...)` block, then a change in `dat()` will cause all blocks containing it to also update (ergo shiny's reactivity). If you want a block to *use* `dat()` but only when something else happens (i.e., not update when `dat()` changes), then use `isolate(dat())` to get to the data without defining a reactive component.

   Two special reactive blocks are `observeEvent` and `eventReactive`, which react to the first argument but nothing in the second expression/argument.
3. Add-on: I use `req` to make sure nothing fires before data or triggers are first valid.

Here's a small app. The intent is this: while the plot is based on the random data, it only updates the plot when you explicitly click the `Plot Now` button. Click on `Random` button and see that the data changes with each press, but the plot does not. Click on `Plot Now` and the plot updates (based on the current state of the data).

```r
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton("rand", "Random"),
      actionButton("btn", "Plot Now")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      textInput("dat", NULL, placeholder = "Random data not ready yet"),
      plotOutput("plt")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    dat <- reactive({
      input$rand
      sample(1e4, size = 10)
    })
    observeEvent(input$rand, {
      # automatically isolated, only input$rand causes updates
      req(dat()) # ensure there is data before trying to update the field
      updateTextInput(session, "dat", value = paste(dat(), collapse = ", "))
    })
    output$plt <- renderPlot({
      thisdat <- req(isolate(dat()))               # both require-valid and not-update
      req(input$btn)                               # just require-valid
      # at this point, we should always have "valid" data
      plot(seq_along(thisdat), thisdat, pch = 16)
    })
  }
)
```

[image: sample shiny]

Comment: Gambit, does this answer your question?